# JS function properties and memory

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

Let's say I have a function with a static property, for example:

```
function Test() {}

Test.someProp = bigObject;
```

I'm wondering if `bigObject` will always be in memory or it will gc sometime?

Comment: Once nothing has a reference to `Test` anymore, it should be GC'd, including the `bigObject`, as long as nothing else has a reference to `bigObject` either

Comment: It works that way even with static properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will never be collected as long as `someProp` is alive (has a reference). If you `delete Test.someProp` or delete or empty the whole `Test` then it will be gCollected

Comment: So what you are saying is that if the code will stay like this, it will never be collected?

Comment: @CertainPerformance doesn't think like you, how can I know who's right?

Comment: Study! But really, he does say the same thing.

Comment: "Once nothing has a reference to Test anymore" - I'm not sure he says the same thing. @CertainPerformance can you clarify please?

Comment: Test belongs to global scope, so it already has a reference there.

Comment: So if it would be inside a closure it will be gone?